# Redirect to a specific URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what i want to do is simple, let's say I have a URL like this `https://www.example.com/pro?type=oil` coming from the URL it could anything like **/pro?type=beans** or **/pro?type=rice** and what I want is to get the URL redirect it to something like this `https://www.example.com/zpro?type=oil`. **PLEASE THE FIRST URL** is /pro? the redirect location is /zpro? Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Slaks to simply redirect whatever is coming from the URL from https://www.example.com/pro?type=oil to this https://www.example.com/zpro?type=oil thats all.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want correctly, the below should do it.

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('/pro?', '/zpro?')
```

Comment: Thank let me try that.

Answer (score 2):

So you can use `window.location.href` to access the string of the current URL. By setting it to a new value, you can change the current URL! So for you, that means setting `window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('/pro', '/zpro')`. This will take the string `/pro` in your URL and redirect to `/zpro` while keeping your query parameters intact!